# List top 20 schools based on number of applicantions for specific schools

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables table school list school ID and school name, and there is another table which contains number of applicants and their state. I need to write a SQL query to list top 20 schools based on number of applicants for specific state (NY, CA)

```
tbl1 columns (SchoolID, Schoolname)
tbl2 columns (applicantID, schoolID, applicantName, state)
```

Thanks,

Comment: *"I need to write..."* - Oddly enough, that means ***you** need to write*. If you are stuck, we can help you, but we (well, I) won't write it for you.

Comment: So, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: What is the purpose of `tbl1` if there's no relation to `tbl2`?

Comment: You don't have any way to link the two tables.

Comment: sorry, forgot to include schoolID is table 2 columns. Both tbls are joined by schoolID

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (assuming tbl2 contains Foreign Key -> SchoolID)

```
SELECT TOP 20   
               tbl1.SchoolID
              ,tbl1.Schoolname
              ,Count(tbl2.applicationID) NumberOfApplicants
FROM  Table1 tbl1 INNER JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl2.SchoolID = tbl1.SchoolID
WHERE tbl2.state = 'CA'
GROUP BY tbl2.state
ORDER BY NumberOfApplicants DESC
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cade/1)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the tbl2 does not have total applicants, but it has applicantID, schoolID, Applicant_name, state). In this case, I have to count number of applicants per state first to get total number of applicants before selecting top 20 schools. Thanks..

Comment: "I have to count number of applicants per state first to get total number of applicants before selecting top 20 schools" - why do you need to do that? Wouldn't it be easier simply to group by `schoolID`?